# XSLT Stylesheet not rendering

Tags: xml, xslt

My XSLT stylesheet will not render and I'm completely stumped as to why.

**Here is my XML:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLTFile.xsl"?>

<Envelope>

  <Guid>1</Guid>
  <Guid>3</Guid>
  <Guid>2</Guid>
</Envelope>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <xsl:value-of select="Envelope/Guid"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output when not running compatibility mode (IE 9):** 1 2 3
**Output when running compatibility mode:**

The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.

---

The stylesheet does not contain a document element. The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed XML documen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your issue: `href="XSLTFile.xsl"` is invalid address of the referenced style sheet. Correct it or put your XSL file in the same location as XML file.

Comment: They are both in the same location. (Root directory)

Comment: nevermind, you were correct I dropped the T in the name. Thanks!